# How to get data from form component and pass to method in React?

Tags: reactjs

In a React project, I have form component which gets input data like email, password and passes to submit method. In a method 'requestOTP' requires email from form component. What could be appropriate solution to get that email data from form and pass to requestOTP method? Below is the code for reference.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Controller
          control={control}
          name="email"
          render={({ onChange, value, ref }) => (
            <Input
              placeholder="EMAIL"
              onChange={onChange}
              ref={ref}
              value={value}
              type="email"
            />
            
          )}
          rules={{
            required: "Please enter email",
            pattern: {
              value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
              message: "Invalid email address"
            }
          }}
        />

   <div className={classes2.root}>
    <Button
        variant="contained"
        type="submit"
      >
          LOG IN
      </Button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(requestOtp)}>
    <Button
        variant="contained"
        type="submit"
      >
                GET AN OTP ON YOUR EMAIL
      </Button>
</form>
```

```
const requestOtp = async (data) => {
{/* I want email data from form component here */}
}
```

Comment: Is that, When you press the login it will pass the email to the backend, and check it's correct or not, then if it was successful response, then you will load the "GET AN OTP ON YOUR EMAIL"?

Comment: Previously I also thought similarly, but, here working is bit different. Like you need Authentication verified hence, OTP would be sent on mail. So for that email is required

Comment: Then why can't send a OTP in same login request?

Comment: Here we need it only for authentication... So, here I want to extract only email value that is onChange when typing in email input. Then get that value and pass to requestOtp method

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: OK... I'll explain you in brief. I have two submit buttons 'Login' and 'Request OTP'. Login accepts two credentials email and password whereas OTP requires only email. Our system is such that for authentication you require OTP to be sent on your email, and then it would be verified and you would be logged in. So for email for OTP, instead of creating new email input, I'am using same email input. As in the code I've created form component for Login and for OTP so I just need email value only on onChange and pass to requestOtp

Answer (score 0):

[onSubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit) event listener already have target values. For example, If you have input tag named 'email' in your form (that is `<input name="email" ... />`)

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
  const email = e.target['email'].value;
  //... and then pass email to the requestOTP function
}
```

Comment: Ya but, this data I'll recieve only on clicking Login button... I want to extract the email value when typing and then pass to requestOtp function